# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present (CORS) - Spring Boot (Spring security) Microservices + Vue.js

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm working on Spring Boot project based on microservices architecture on backend and Vue.js on frontend.
Structure of my project is next:
[image: Project structure]

For avoiding CORS error usually I add `@CrossOrigin` annotation on to class and it works.
It was all good and has been working well, until I added **security part** with ability to login users.

#### What did I did:

**1.** To API Gateway that built on `spring-cloud-gateway` I've added `AuthFilter` that uses as interceptor to create and check JWT:
`api-gateway/src/main/java/.../AuthFilter.java`

```
@Component
public class AuthFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<AuthFilter.Config> {
    private final WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

    @Autowired
    public AuthFilter(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        super(Config.class);
        this.webClientBuilder = webClientBuilder;
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            if(!exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().containsKey(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Missing auth information");
            }

            String authHeader = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION).get(0);
            String[] parts = authHeader.split(" ");

            if(parts.length != 2 || !"Bearer".equals(parts[0])) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Incorrect auth structure");
            }

            return webClientBuilder.build()
                    .post()
                    .uri("http://manager-service/api/v1/auth/validateToken?token=" + parts[1])
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(EmployeeDTO.class) //EmployeeDTO.class is custom DTO that represents User
                    .map(user -> {
                        exchange.getRequest()
                                .mutate()
                                .header("x-auth-user-id", user.getId());
                        return exchange;
                    }).flatMap(chain::filter);

        };
    }

    public static class Config {
        //live it empty because we dont need any particular configuration
    }
}
```

**2.** I've added `AuthFilter` as filter to each service in `application.properties`:
`api-gateway/src/resource/application.properties`

```
##Workshop service routes
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=workshop-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://workshop-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/api/v1/workshop/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=AuthFilter

##Manage service routes
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=manager-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://manager-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/api/v1/manage/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[0]=AuthFilter

##Manage service for singIn. Here we dont need to add AuthFilter, cause sign in page should be available for all
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].id=manager-service-sign-in
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].uri=lb://manager-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[0]=Path=/api/v1/auth/signIn

...
```

**3.** Manager-service microservice used to control base entities for system, such as users, roles, organizations where users working are and so on, so here I added `SecurityConfig` and `WebConfig`, because this microservice will be responsible for JWT generating: 
`manager-service/src/main/java/.../SecurityConfig.java`

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig  {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
   }
```

`manager-service/src/main/java/.../WebConfig.java`

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final Long MAX_AGE=3600L;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedHeaders(
                        HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
                        HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,
                        HttpHeaders.ACCEPT)
                .allowedMethods(
                        HttpMethod.GET.name(),
                        HttpMethod.POST.name(),
                        HttpMethod.PUT.name(),
                        HttpMethod.DELETE.name())
                .maxAge(MAX_AGE)
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8100")
                .allowCredentials(false);
    }
}
```

**4.** In controller, that represents auth I also added `@CrossOrigin` annotation to class:
`manager-service/src/main/java/.../AuthController.java`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/auth")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8100")
@Slf4j
public class AuthController {
    private final AuthService authService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthController(AuthService authService) {
        this.authService = authService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/signIn")
    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO> signIn(@RequestBody CredentialsDTO credentialsDTO) {
        log.info("Trying to login {}", credentialsDTO.getLogin());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(EmployeeMapper.convertToDTO(authService.signIn(credentialsDTO)));
    }

    @PostMapping("/validateToken")
    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO> validateToken(@RequestParam String token) {
        log.info("Trying to validate token {}", token);
        Employee validatedTokenUser = authService.validateToken(token);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(EmployeeMapper.convertToDTO(validatedTokenUser));
    }
}
```

**5.** For frontend I use Vue.js. For requests I use `axios`. Here are `post`-request to login:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/signIn', this.credentials).then(response => {
              console.log('response = ', response)
              console.log('token from response', response.data.token)
              this.$store.commit('saveToken', response.data.token)
            }).catch(error => {
          console.log('Error is below')
          console.log(error)
        })
```

All what I'm getting is an error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/signIn' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`. Below you'll see headers, that displays Chrome with request:
[image]
I've been trying to add another one `corsConfiguration`, tried to mark with `CrossOrigin` annotation only method, not class at all but it hadn't take any effects. If I try to make such requests with **postman** it gives me expected response with generated token.

I'll be grateful for any idea what could I do wrong.
Thanks!

**UPDATE:** As I understood well - all problems is in `api-gateway`. If I make requests directly to service - I get right response, but if I make request through **gateway** - I'm facing an error, logs of `api-gateway` below:

```
2022-07-05 00:34:18.128 TRACE 8105 --- [or-http-epoll-5] o.s.c.g.h.p.PathRoutePredicateFactory    : Pattern "[/api/v1/workshop/**]" does not match against value "/api/v1/auth/signIn"
2022-07-05 00:34:18.129 TRACE 8105 --- [or-http-epoll-5] o.s.c.g.h.p.PathRoutePredicateFactory    : Pattern "[/api/v1/manage/**]" does not match against value "/api/v1/auth/signIn"
2022-07-05 00:34:18.129 TRACE 8105 --- [or-http-epoll-5] o.s.c.g.h.p.PathRoutePredicateFactory    : Pattern "/api/v1/auth/signIn" matches against value "/api/v1/auth/signIn"
2022-07-05 00:34:18.129 DEBUG 8105 --- [or-http-epoll-5] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route matched: manager-service-sign-in
2022-07-05 00:34:18.129 DEBUG 8105 --- [or-http-epoll-5] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/signIn] to Route{id='manager-service-sign-in', uri=lb://manager-service, order=0, predicate=Paths: [/api/v1/auth/signIn], match trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[], metadata={}}
2022-07-05 00:34:18.129 DEBUG 8105 --- [or-http-epoll-5] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : [e5b87280-8] Mapped to org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler@78df1cfc
```

Comment: Please consider shortening your question to the minimum of information required to understand the problem and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research I've solved problem. **It was all Gateway's fault**
As I mentioned before, direct request gives me right response, but only if I go through `api-gateway` it gives me an errors.

### So solution is to add CORS Configuration rules to gateway:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Origin Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, RETAIN_UNIQUE
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "http://localhost:8100"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
            allowedMethods: "*"
```

Please, note that if you don't add section with `gateway: default-filters` you will be facing similar error with header that contains multiple values.

Thanks to [answer by Pablo Aragonés in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70985763) and [Spring Cloud Documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi__cors_configuration.html)

Comment: For Spring Cloud Gateway 2022.0.3 It's not working. Any idea for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

add this to applications.yml in your gateway, solved issue for me:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
    default-filters:
       - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Origin Access-Control- 
       Allow-Credentials, RETAIN_UNIQUE
  globalcors:
    corsConfigurations:
      '[/**]':
        allowedOrigins: "http://localhost:<your port>"
        allowedHeaders: "*"
        allowedMethods: "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue & got resolved by defining following bean in my Configuration.

```
@Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:8100")); // Provide list of origins if you want multiple origins
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
```

You can comment out all other details e.g. `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8100"), WebConfig.java, SecurityConfig.java` as once we define above bean these things are not required.

Your code may not be running because you have defined bean , security config as well as webconfig which might be conflicting while processing your request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't help me. I've added this bean to ```Application.java``` class, commented before, as you said, annotation, WebConfig and SecurityConfig. Anyway, doesn't it the same do that ```addCorsMappings``` in WebConfig?

Comment: Yes, it is. In my case I even used `addCorsMappings` but it didn't worked. Can you check what error you are getting is it same?

Comment: Yes, it's still the same error. I've tried to do like you said and even tried to mix it with Security config and still facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

#I had the same issue. I added these lines which are in the first answer

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Origin Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, RETAIN_UNIQUE
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "http://localhost:8100"(or frontend link)
            allowedHeaders: "*"
            allowedMethods: "*"
```