# Spring cloud gateway + service with websockets + angular result in CORS error

Tags: angular, cors, spring-websocket, spring-cloud-gateway

I have recently added websocket configuration to my spring application, which is behind a Spring cloud gateway. There is also an angular app which communicates with my service through the gateway. The pronlem is that when i try co connect to it this is the error that i get in the mozilla: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8050/escrow-service/ws/info?t=1663539514537. (Reason: Multiple CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ not allowed)`

and this is in edge:  `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8050/some-service/ws/info?t=1663599778176' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:4200, http://localhost:4200', but only one is allowed.`

When I try connecting directly to my app without going trough gateway, everything works as it should.

This is the code for the web-socket configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/notification");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/product");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addEndpoint("/ws")
            .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
            .withSockJS();
    }
}
```

this is the code handling the cors in the gateway:

```
private CorsWebFilter corsFilter() {
        /*
         CORS requests are managed only if headers Origin and Access-Control-Request-Method are available on OPTIONS requests
         (this filter is simply ignored in other cases).

         This filter can be used as a replacement for the @Cors annotation.
        */
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.addAllowedHeader(ORIGIN);
        config.addAllowedHeader(CONTENT_TYPE);
        config.addAllowedHeader(ACCEPT);
        config.addAllowedHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
        config.addAllowedHeader(CONNECTION);
        config.addAllowedHeader(ACCEPT_ENCODING);
        config.addAllowedHeader(USER_AGENT);
        config.addAllowedHeader(CONTENT_LENGTH);
        config.addAllowedHeader(HOST);
        config.addAllowedHeader("Postman-Token");
        config.addAllowedHeader(COOKIE);
        config.addAllowedMethod(GET);
        config.addAllowedMethod(PUT);
        config.addAllowedMethod(POST);
        config.addAllowedMethod(OPTIONS);
        config.addAllowedMethod(DELETE);
        config.addAllowedMethod(PATCH);
        config.setMaxAge(3600L);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

        return new CorsWebFilter(source);
    }
```

And this is the angular code for calling the endpoints:

```
connect() {
        console.log("Initialize WebSocket Connection");
        const _this = this;

        let socket = new SockJS(this.appComponent.connectionUrl);
        let destinationUrl=this.appComponent.destinationUrl;
        _this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        _this.stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            _this.stompClient.subscribe(destinationUrl, function (greeting: any) {
                let obj = JSON.parse(greeting.body);
                console.log(obj);
                _this.onMessageReceived(obj);
            });
        });
    };
```

Comment: I think this has to be more specific `config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Collections.singletonList("*"));`. Wildcards, or a list with a wildcard is not correct IF I remember correctly.

Comment: don't think this is the issue, it is not that the origin is not added, the issue is that it is add two times, and my guess is that the WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer  has something to do with it

Comment: Well, I don't know who is adding `'http://localhost:4200, http://localhost:4200'`, but Edge seems to be describing the issue fairly specifically.

Comment: my guess is that one time the gateway is adding it and the second time is the spring app itself

Comment: Yea but why `http://localhost:4200`

Comment: this is the url of my angular app, i guess this is the origin that is added twice

Comment: Perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70983244/use-spring-gateway-and-getting-error-access-control-allow-origin-header-conta.

Comment: the idea looks ok, now we have to find a way to add it programatically not declarative

Comment: it worked, I will share the solution in a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After commenting with K.Nicholas, I found the solution and added it programatically as everywhere, there was only declarative solution.

```
@Bean
    public RouteLocator applicationRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                
                .route(p -> p.path("/my-service/**")
                        .filters(gatewayFilterSpec -> gatewayFilterSpec
                                .rewritePath("/escrow-service/(?<remaining>.*)", "/${remaining}")
                                .dedupeResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","RETAIN_UNIQUE")
                                .dedupeResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","RETAIN_UNIQUE")
                                .filter(customLoggingFilter))
                        .uri("lb://my-service/"))
                .build();
    }
```

the key was in adding

```
.dedupeResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","RETAIN_UNIQUE")
.dedupeResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","RETAIN_UNIQUE")
```

these headers so that the duplicates are removed.